# Binding values from ng-repeat in Angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I'm loading data from a database and save it to an array as follows:

```
$scope.allGroups = [{id: 1, groupName: group1}, {id: 2, groupName: group2}, ..]
```

In my view, I'm trying to select multiple group names as follows:

```
<div
  class="drag-container avaliable-groups-connect groups-container schedule-container"
>
  <div class="group" ng-repeat="m in allGroups">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="m.selected" />
    <span>{{ m.groupName }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to save selected items (`m.selected`) to an array one-by-one and bind that array to `ng-model="schedule.selectedGroups"`

How can I perform that? Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="group" ng-repeat="m in allGroups" ng-init="m.selected = false">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="m.selected" />
   <span>{{ m.groupName }}</span>
</div>
```

Now your checkbox ng-model with modify the variable to true or false and in your js code
you can do like below.

```
$scope.schedule.selectedGroups = $scope.allGroups.filter(function (data) {
     return data.selected === true;
});
```